# Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, error-handling

```
class Option{
  public static void main ( String[] args ){
    if ( args[0].equals( "-en" )){
     System.out.println( "English Option" ) ;
    } else if ( args[0].equals( "-es" )){
        System.out.println( "Spanish Option") ;     
     }
     else System.out.println( "Unrecognized option" ) ;
  }
}
```

when trying to run this I get this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at Option.main(Option.java:5)

I'm new to coding sorry if this is simple but im stuck

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that you are not passing any *command argument* when you launch the program, so the length of `args` is `0`. Therefore, you can't access to its first element:

```
args[0]
```

You can pass a [command-line argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) like

```
java Option argument_here
```

In your case it could be:

```
java Option -en
java Option -es
```

But you can also **handle** the case when you don't pass any arguments checking if the length of `args` is `0`:

```
if (args.length == 0)
    System.out.println("No arguments passed.");
else {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you supply no arguments when you run the program, then `args` has length zero and there is no `args[0]` element. Before checking the first arg, you should test whether `args.length > 0`. For example:

```
public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    if (args.length == 1) {
        if ( args[0].equals( "-en" ))
        {
         System.out.println( "English Option" ) ;
        }
         else if ( args[0].equals( "-es" ))
         {
            System.out.println( "Spanish Option") ;     
         }
         else System.out.println( "Unrecognized option" ) ;
    } else {
         // zero or more than one option
         System.out.println( "Usage: java Option [-en | -es]" ) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always account for not having args[0] before checking for a value in args[0]